# writing xml files

Tags: c++, xml

Suppose I want to write files and store them as xml files. How do I do that? I've never dealt with xml files before and I was wondering how you'd do that and if you have any useful comments on where to start!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/)

Comment: A c++ wrapper for tinyxml is [ticpp](http://ticpp.googlecode.com)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean writing XML to a file, Just write it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("test.xml");
  myfile << "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><book></book>";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You almost always do not want to just write it, as you will end up having to create a large amount of validation and escaping code which has been written and tested already in freely available libraries.

Comment: Yes, but when the question is short and the goal is unknown. Maybe easiest solution is better.

Comment: validation is an issue more for reading than writing xml. In most cases of just exporting some xml data, plain writing is best. That said, the above snippet is wrong, as it doesn't escape "s

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to write/read XML files on Windows is to use XmlLite parser:

["Small And Fast XML Parser For Native C++"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx)

You also have working [samples from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752864.aspx).